# Sum if in multiple sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sumifs

I am looking for funcion/code for Google Sheet document which would enable me to sum hours (numbers) on multiple sheets based  on names.

Basically I need this to create a prediction tool for project hours allocation to control potential overbooking of hours.

Here's link to the file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-MGD1E7uj7_wkGoDPDH_Qgc-jRKJH55d2TvMG9VsBk/edit?usp=sharing

Sheets will be regurarly updated.

I've tried to use INDIRECT funcion but I see that doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this function: I've modified the location of your sheets' names since it would be overlapped if you had more names. With MAKEARRAY it creates the chart counting the names, and with REDUCE it sums the values of each sheet you have in your range. Adapt the ranges accordingly to your source sheet!

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A6:A),COUNTA(B5:5),LAMBDA(r,c,
REDUCE(,A2:B4,LAMBDA(a,b,a+  IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&b&"'!B4:M"),  MATCH(INDEX(A6:A,r),INDIRECT("'"&b&"'!A4:A"),0),  MATCH(INDEX(B5:5,,c),INDIRECT("'"&b&"'!B3:3"),0)))))))
```

[image]

NOTE: Be aware of having matching names in your cells with your actual sheets. You had 'Project 1' instead of 'Project1'

Comment: Thanks Martin, that's very helpful!

I've tried to replicate solutions in my draft but I couldn't do it. Could you check my formula in cell B60?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/192lXwtQt_oEBiFQcOzAP9-C2EqRmvL0-Oj38Y-m1Uzk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You had one comma not translated in semi colon in your locale 

Comment: Hi Martin, do you know how I can achieve similar results in Excel? The number of projects expanded to >80 and google sheets don't have enough computing power to process the formula.